# why user not able to select image after remove?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Could you please tell me why I am not able to select “image” after delete of row.

Steps to reproduce.

1 ) select any image from file chooser example “a.png”

2) delete/remove that item from list using remove button .

3) again select “a.png” from the file chooser .Why it is not showing in list?

Here is my code

https://plnkr.co/edit/6xlFlfjXFnvvd0Ll6UnD?p=preview

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.poiImageData = []
});
```

Comment: plnkr not working.

Comment: plunker is working please check again.. !! https://plnkr.co/edit/6xlFlfjXFnvvd0Ll6UnD?p=preview